Не понимаю, почему выводится элемент массива, а не адрес его памяти
int array[5]{1,24,5,61,4}
int *p = array + 2 

Почему я получаю элемент массива, а не его адрес в памяти? ведь запись выше, эквивалентна (= &array + 2), заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, я новичок в плюсах, и очень хочу разобраться с указателями. В коде выходит, что можно свободно обращаться к p[0] как к массиву, и соответственно манипулировать. Но мне не понятно, почему в данном обращении я получаю элемент массива, а не его адрес в памяти, если я не разыменовываю его.
При выводе через сиаут, я получаю адрес, почему при указателе результат другой? Ведь я получаю int* (адресный тип), но далее p[0], никак его не разыменовываю. Извините, если нагородил глупостей, вполне могу много не понимать и соответственно неправильно мыслить..
 std::cout << array + 2 << std::endl;


как задать хороший вопрос. начните с более конкретной формулировки заголовка вопроса.

в p[0] когда мы обращаемся к элементу массива, то он автоматом разыминовывается. если нужен адрес то напиши &p[0]. Не помню точно но std::cout вроде автоматом разыменовывает array + 2. попробуй printf("%p", array + 2);

почитайте про арифметику указателей. array + 2 тождественно array[2]

видимо проблема с сиаутом, потому что сиаут выводит array + 2 , + 2 элемента от константного адреса, а вот *(array+2) вы выводит уже сам элемент

Либо тщательно изучайте кресты, либо просто используйте printf (полчаса на чтение manpage)

А что значит "получаю элемент массива, а не его адрес в памяти"? У меня  'int *p = arr + 2;' записывает в p адрес элемента с индексом 2, а не его значение.

@SergeyTatarintsev *(array + 2) тождественно array[2], звездочку обронили.

Вопрос очень непонятно написан. Не надо говорить словами ("в данном обращении я получаю элемент массива", бла бла, в данном - это в каком?), показывайте кодом. Пишите строку, которую запускаете, что она печатает, и что вы ожидали увидеть.


ведь запись выше, эквивалентна (= &array + 2)

Не эквивалентна. Хотя array (который автоматически преобразуется в адрес первого элемента массива) и &array (адрес всего массива) - это одно и то же число, у них разные типы (array автоматически превращается в int *, а &array - это int (*)[5] - "указатель на массив из пяти intов"),
Поэтому + и [] ведут себя с ними по-разному.
+ i прибавляет к указателю i * sizeof(T), где T - тип, на который указывает указатель (int в первом случае и int[5] во втором).

В коде выходит, что можно свободно обращаться к p[0] как к массиву

Неправда. К p можно обращаться как к массиву (p[0]), а к самому p[0], очевидно, нельзя (p[0][0] не работает).

почему в данном обращении я получаю элемент массива, а не его адрес в памяти

a[i] - то же самое, что *(a + i). [] разыменовывает указатель автоматически.
Из этого следует, что a[0] - то же самое, что просто *a.

При выводе через сиаут, я получаю адрес, почему при указателе результат другой?

Не понял.

int (*)[5]- "указатель на массив из двух intов" — тогда уж (по задаче) int (*)[4]- "указатель на массив из четырех intов"

@Harry Спасибо, поправил. В первом кусочке кода 5, возьму его.
